# WDK8 - Where is winusb.h?

Tags: windows, usb, wdk, winusb

I am trying to use WinUSB in my project. The guide I am following is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540174.aspx. This article tells me to include the following files:

```
// Include Windows headers
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

// Include WinUSB headers
#include <winusb.h>
#include <Usb100.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
```

The files `windows.h`, `setupapi.h`, and `strsafe.h` were found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include`.

Files `usb100.h` was found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared`.

And the files `stdio.h`, `tchar.h` were found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include`.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450839(v=vs.85).aspx, winusb.h is located in WDK8's Include\um folder, however after installing the WDK8 three times with both the pre-download and download methods, the file isn't there. I'm assuming that by `Include\um`, they're reffering to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`. I've also done a search of my system and couldn't find `winusb.h` anywhere.

I also can't find `winapifamily.h` which, according to the second msdn page I linked, is included by `winusb.h`.

I'm on Windows 7 x64, with WDK8 and VC++ Express installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing the Windows 8 SDK, I was able to find `winusb.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`.

It appears that since version 8, `winusb.h` moved from the the WDK/DDK to the SDK.

Answer (score 3):

`winusb.h` is a part of the Windows DDK, and can (when the DDK is installed) be found under `WINDDK\<BuildNumber>\inc\ddk`.

More info how to make it work (including info on the file locations) can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540174(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Windows DDK has been renamed since version 8.0 to the WDK. I'm using the latest WDK and winusb.h isn't there.

Comment: In the 8.0 version, it's in `WDKDIR\<BuildNumber>\Include\um` ( `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um`), so if you don't have it there, something seems wrong. (Verified in my fresh install, not just a "I read it above")

Comment: Do you happen to have Windows 8 SDK installed as well? I have a hunch that MS either moved winusb.h to the SDK, or the WDK won't install the file if SDK8 isn't installed.

Comment: @DanielK Yes, I have 7.0/7.1A/8.0/8.0A SDK directories (although 7.1A seems to be the only full install, the others seem to only contain partial/extension SDKs installed by VS2012)